# These drivers are identical according to the UI. Why does the scripted one not work?

Tags: animation, scripting, drivers, bezier-curves

I have put a driver on the tilt attribute of a bezier curve, and linked it to a hook manually first to see if it would work. The result of this is as follows:

[image: Manual]

And here you can see that the bezier curve tilts along with the Hook perfectly:
[image: Manual result]

It did what it was supposed to do, so I went on to do the same with a python script. The result of both seems identical to me, but the scripted version does not work. Here is the picture of the scripted driver:

[image: Scripted]

And here is a picture of the hook being tilted, but the bezier curve not moving along with the hook (and to prove that the hook is connected correctly, a bit of y-axis rotation as well):

[image: Scripted result]

Is there some internal activation that needs to take place for the driver to start functioning?

Finally for reference, here is the code that created this driver:

```
# IMPORT LIBRARIES
import bpy
import csv
from os import system

# CLEAR CONSOLE
cls = lambda: system('cls')
cls()

# START
width = 1
thickness = 0.2

# START WITH INITIALIZING CROSS SECTION
CrossSection = bpy.data.curves.new('Cross Section Curve', type='CURVE')
CrossSection.dimensions = '3D'
CrossSection.resolution_u = 12

polyline = CrossSection.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(3)
polyline.points[0].co = (-width/2, thickness/2, 0, 1)
polyline.points[1].co = (-width/2, -thickness/2, 0, 1)
polyline.points[2].co = (width/2, -thickness/2, 0, 1)
polyline.points[3].co = (width/2, thickness/2, 0, 1)

# Create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('Cross Section', CrossSection)

# Attach to scene
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(curveOB)

# Select object and set it to cyclic
bpy.data.objects["Cross Section"].select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Cross Section']
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.curve.cyclic_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')


# INITIALIZE UNIT MIDLINE NEXT
MidLine = bpy.data.curves.new('MidLine Curve', type='CURVE')
MidLine.dimensions = '3D'
MidLine.resolution_u = 12

polyline = MidLine.splines.new('BEZIER')
polyline.bezier_points.add(1)
print(len(polyline.bezier_points))

polyline.bezier_points[0].handle_left = (-1, 0, 0)
polyline.bezier_points[0].handle_right = (1, 0, 0)
polyline.bezier_points[0].co = (0, 0, 0)

polyline.bezier_points[1].handle_left = (3-1, 0, 0)
polyline.bezier_points[1].handle_right = (3+1, 0, 0)
polyline.bezier_points[1].co = (3, 0, 0)

# Create Object
curveOB = bpy.data.objects.new('MidLine', MidLine)

# Attach to scene
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(curveOB)

# Select object and assign the cross section bevel
bpy.data.objects["MidLine"].select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['MidLine']
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.context.object.data.bevel_mode = 'OBJECT'
bpy.context.object.data.bevel_object = bpy.data.objects["Cross Section"]
bpy.context.object.data.splines[0].use_smooth = False
bpy.context.object.data.use_fill_caps = True
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')
#bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
#bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# CREATE THE HOOKS AND LINK THEM TO THE CONTROL POINTS
# Control point 1
bpy.context.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].select_control_point = True
bpy.context.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].select_right_handle = True
bpy.context.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[0].select_left_handle = True
bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()
bpy.data.objects['Empty'].name = "Control Point 1"

driver = bpy.data.curves['MidLine Curve'].splines[0].bezier_points[0].driver_add("tilt").driver

var = driver.variables.new()
var.name = "tilt_rot_1"
var.type = 'TRANSFORMS'
var.targets[0].id = bpy.data.objects["Control Point 1"]
var.targets[0].transform_type = 'ROT_X'
var.targets[0].rotation_mode = 'AUTO'

# Driver does not work so far....
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Control point 2
bpy.context.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].select_control_point = True
bpy.context.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].select_right_handle = True
bpy.context.active_object.data.splines[0].bezier_points[1].select_left_handle = True
bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()
bpy.data.objects['Empty'].name = "Control Point 2"

driver = bpy.data.curves['MidLine Curve'].splines[0].bezier_points[1].driver_add("tilt").driver

var = driver.variables.new()
var.name = "tilt_rot_2"
var.type = 'TRANSFORMS'
var.targets[0].id = bpy.data.objects["Control Point 2"]
var.targets[0].transform_type = 'ROT_X'
var.targets[0].rotation_mode = 'AUTO'

# Driver does not work so far....

# SET HOOKS TO XYZ-AXES AND QUATERNIONS, AND HIDE CROSS SECTION
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.data.objects['Control Point 1'].empty_display_type = "ARROWS"
bpy.data.objects['Control Point 1'].rotation_mode = "QUATERNION"
bpy.data.objects['Control Point 2'].empty_display_type = "ARROWS"
bpy.data.objects['Control Point 2'].rotation_mode = "QUATERNION"
bpy.data.objects['Cross Section'].hide_viewport = True
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

Hopefully someone knows the answer to this peculiar problem.

Thanks!

Comment: First thing that jumps out re images is expression in scripted driver is 0.0.   When add a driver `driver.expression = "tilt_rot_1"`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I fully understand what you mean. Is ```driver.expression = "tilt_rot_1"``` something I should have specified in my code? Because currently I did not. I also don't fully understand what you refer to when you say "expression in scripted driver is 0.0"?

Comment: Play "spot the difference between two images. In first the expresson field is "var + 0.0" in the second it is "0.0". In first it evaluates to same value as var, in second, driver evaluates to 0.0  The driver value of a scripted  expression type is the script evaluation of `driver.expression`.  Eg in second case  `eval("0.0")`  A variable named "var" can be used in expresson as `var`.

Comment: Holy crap! That actually worked! Thank you so much haha. I can't believe I missed that. I guess I just don't understand how drivers function completely yet. Thanks again! :P
(If you post an answer can I mark it as the correct solution?)

Comment: The expression field is useful because it lets you do operations on any number of variables. Most drivers you will directly use the default `var`, but often, you'll need to do some operation(s) over it or other variables, and the expression field takes care of it.

Comment: the Blender not scripts in automatic mode you need active in preferences